# Making a simple GPA calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to make a gpa calculator using javascript. First the user should be prompt to enter the number of classes they are taking. Then prompt the user to enter a letter grade for each class. Now i know that it needs to be in a loop so I put it in a for loop and have it working. But my problem is i can not figure out how to get the letter that a person enters to translate to the corresponding number (ex. a/A = 4.0, b/B = 3.0 and so on). This is what I have so far. Any ideas on what to do from here? `

```
    {
       var n = prompt("Enter Number of Classes");

       for (x = n; x >= 1; x--) {
           var t = prompt("Enter Letter Grade");

           function computeNumericGrade(Grade) {
               var a = t.matchMedia('a', 'A');
               a === 4.0;
               var b = t.matchMedia('b', 'B');
               b === 3.0;
               var c = t.matchMedia('c', 'C');
               c === 2.0;
               var d = t.matchMedia('d', 'D');
               d === 1.0;
               var e = t.matchMedia('e', 'E');
               e === 0;
           }
       }

       document.write(a);
   }
```

Comment: === is a comparison operator to check if two values are the same = assigns values to variables.

Comment: Stack Overflow has [many other questions that are very similar to this one](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+gpa+calculator).

Comment: oh, you've got a ways to go. You need to use "if", and you need to sum grades, call your function, compute the average, etc.

Comment: So... this wouldn't, by any chance, be 'homework,' would it?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to lower case, and operate with the character code:

```js
4 + 'a'.charCodeAt(0) - t.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0)
```